# Mongoose fails insertion for insertMany when a specific index is defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose fails to make insertion when the `insertMany` command is used to insert documents into the database. I have around 2000 documents which I want to insert and instead of saving each one of them one by one I am trying to use the insertMany function for saving it.

If no specific index is defined then it takes a huge time to just save it in the database and if an index is defined the connection gets timed out as soon as the insertion operation takes place.

```
Model.insertMany(documents, function(batchSaveError, savedDocs) {
  if (batchSaveError) {
    callback(batchSaveError);
  } else {
    callback(null);
  }
});
```

This is the code that I am trying to get done.

Comment: share some code please

Comment: there seems no problem in the code above. i have inserted even 7000 items together with a success

Comment: Do I need to have a objectID predefined in those documents that I am inserting?

Comment: no insertMany should assign ObjectId on document creation

Comment: It seems to work fine in local, but fails whenever I try it over a free mLab server. Is mLab having some kind of restrictions over it?

Comment: yes you must be using free account ? which has limitation

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed pretty vague. The connection timeout seemed pretty normal and can happen in any scenario. But whenever the connection times out mongoose tries to reconnect all by itself.

What I was missing was, I was not capturing the `error` event for the connection safely and that was causing the whole application to crash. Just when I added a proper catch statement for the error event, although it timed out a few times but the insertion went pretty fine and smoot.